# passing a global javascript variable into jquery plugins on resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am creating a mobile first responsive web site that has a few custom jquery plugins which kick in at certain breakpoints.

First, snippets of the code, and then ill explain the issue...

**CSS:**

```
@media (min-width: 20em) {
  html:after {
    content: "320";
     } }
@media (min-width: 25em) {
  html:after {
    content: "400";
     } }
@media (min-width: 30em) {
  html:after {
    content: "480";
     } }
```

**GLOBAL JS**

```
var FOO = {
 mq: function() {
   return  parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(document.documentElement,':after').getPropertyValue('content').replace(/['"]/g,''),10);                     
 }
}
```

**JQUERY PLUGIN 1**

```
this.init = function()
{
 $(window).on("load resize orientationchange", function() {
   if(FOO.mq() >= 480) {
      DO SOMETHING
   }
});
};
```

**JQUERY PLUGIN 2**

```
this.init = function()
{
 $(window).on("load resize orientationchange", function() {
   if(FOO.mq() >= 560) {
      DO SOMETHING ELSE
   }
});
};
```

Now the problem with putting the FOO.mq() in the jquery plugin is that it will fire the FOO.mq() function for every DOM object found (e.g. if the plugin does something to 10 images it will fire the FF.mq() 10 times) where really thats not needed as we only need to check once.

I have tried putting the resize/return value in a global object but it nevers seems to work and gets picked up bu the jquery plugins.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You want to hear about [enquire.js](http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/).

Comment: You made a mistake somewhere. Your event only bound to `window` unless you have event with the same type bubbling somewhere

Comment: can't you get `FOO.mq()` to calculate its stuff once (and whenever a relevant event occurs) rather than on demand?

Comment: @Alnitak thats what im trying to do but cannot get it to work

Comment: @Adi so what events will result in the value of `FOO.mq` changing?

Comment: @Alnitak will return the html:after value (from css) so ideally want to do that and return that globally and various plugins and see that value and not keep checking it

Comment: @Adi and once the page is loaded it never changes?

Comment: @Alnitak no, it can change on resize and orientation

Comment: @Adi OK, my updated answer should allow for that, then.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that this calculated value only changes on document load, or if the window changes layout:

```
var FOO = FOO || {};      // create global namespace obj, if required
$(function() {
    var mq;               // scoped variable

    // catch events that might change the @media CSS rules
    $(window).on("load resize orientationchange", function() {
        mq = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(document.documentElement,':after').getPropertyValue('content').replace(/['"]/g,''),10);
    });

    FOO.mq = function() { // function that just returns the scoped variable
        return mq;
    }
});
```

Comment: If i put a console.log(FOO.mq()) outside of this I get a 'TypeError: FOO.mq is not a function' error. Any ideas? I can see what you're trying to do and I think the idea is great

Comment: You won't be able to call `FOO.mq` until _after_ the document.ready handler has been invoked.

Comment: this must be becasue the js is firing before the window load is fired thinking about it (which gives the variable a value)

Comment: Yes, I believe it does.  I don't recall at which point you can reliably call `window.getComputedStyle()` but whatever happens you'll need to ensure you don't try to use `FOO.mq()` until after this function has been called.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a timeout:

```
this.init = function () {
    var timeout;
    $(window).on("load resize orientationchange", function () {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(function(){
           if (FOO.mq() >= 480) {
               DO SOMETHING
           }
        },15);//even 0 should be enough
    });
};
```